# Running angular 2 app with npm start creates huge memory dump files

Tags: angular, npm

I am new to Angular 2. I have created an application using angular 2 which runs successfully. 
When i run the command "npm start" and once the application is running on the browser, heavy files get created under "Debug dump files" with size 961mb and "System error memory dump files" -961mb.
Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: does there is any code inside your app which causes memory occupation?

Comment: I have initialized array in the Component, inside ngOnit like this                   
occupations = [];

Comment: are you using web pack or angular cli?

Comment: None of these.. I used the quickstart seed project from angular 2 website. Cloned it using git. and executed npm install. After that written all components and now i use npm start to start the application. Correct me if i am going wrong way.